# how to get the number of declare-funs in smt2 instance in z3(api)

Tags: z3

I used the *Z3_parse_smtlib2_file(c,Z3_string,0,0,0,num_decl,&decl_names,&decls)* to try to get the variables and the quantity of variables. But the value of *num_decl* still be zero.
What I consider the value will be become as the different smt2 files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `num_decls`, `decl_names` and `decls` are input parameters. They are used to initialize the SMT 2.0 parser symbol table with declarations created using the C API.
The current Z3 API does not provide procedures for extracting the sorts and functions declared in a file/string in SMT 2.0 format. This information is available internally. See the files in the following directories in the Z3 distribution `src/parsers/smt2` and `src/cmd_context/cmd_context.*`.